# Como se utilizan los argumentos en el constructor __init__ i como pasar-los a las funciones

Tags: python, constructor

tengo dos dudas y quería ver si me podrían ayudar.
Mi duda es, como funcionan los argumentos en el constructor.

Me intentaré explicar más.

Vamos a decir que queremos hacer una class:

```
class coche():
```

Ahora vamos a decir que queremos hacer un constructor:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.plazas = 7
    self.velocidad = 230 
    self.nuevo = True
```

Ahora hecho el constructor vamos a hacer algunas funciones:

```
#ejemplo_funciones

def Volkswagen(self):
    if self.nuevo == True and self.velocidad and not self.plazas:
        return "Es un Volkswagen"

def Audi(self):
    if self.nuevo == False and self.plazas == 2:
        return "Es un Audi"

def Toyota(self):
    if self.nuevo == False and self.velocidad and self.plazas:
        return "Es un Toyota"
```

*mi primera duda es esta:*

**Cuando es tengo que pasar argumentos en el constructor, ya que en el constructor solo puse (self)
, y dentro del constructor hay:**

```
    self.plazas = 7
    self.velocidad = 230 
    self.nuevo = True
```

Si no me explique, intentaré representar-lo con un ejemplo para que me digáis si es lo mismo o no:

```
#opcionn_1
def __init__(self):
    self.plazas = 7
    self.velocidad = 230 
    self.nuevo = True
```

---

```
#opcionn_2

def __init__(self,plazas,velocidad,nuevo):
    self.plazas = 7
    self.velocidad = 230 
    self.nuevo = True
```

Sería lo mismo?
Porque vi códigos que utilizaba la `#opcion_1` pero otros códigos utilizaban la `#opcion_2`.

Mi segunda duda es:

**Si utilizo un constructor cuál son los argumentos que tengo que pasar a las funciones:**

1-los argumentos del constructor
2-lo que hay dentro del constructor dependiendo de que necesite cada función, como se realizó arriba en `#ejemplo_funciones`.
3-los dos son correctos

El codigo escrito arriba es un ejemplo y seguramente este mal, si esta mal utilizado el `self.` en las funciones se agradeceria que me lo podrian decir para tener-lo en cuenta.

Gracias de antemano!!

así lo utilizaria bien?

```
class Calculadora():
def __init__(self,suma,resta,division,multipliacion):

    self.suma = True
    self.resta = resta
    self.division = division
    self.multipliacion = spare_mark

def suma(self,suma):
numbers = (2,3,4,5,6,7)
 
for i in numbers
    if self.suma == True:
    return numbers[0] + numbers[1]
```

Comment: Siendo precisos, el método `__init__` es un _inicializador_. La instancia `self` ya está creada al entrar al método. Estos atributos los podrías haber creado en otro método o, incluso, a continuación de donde has creado la instancia. Por coveniencia, se pasan al método `__init__` argumentos con el mismo nombre que el atributo que vas a inicializar.

Comment: Okeii, lo tendre que poner en practica para que lo entienda mejor, pero Muchas Gracias!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma *normal* es esta:

```
def __init__(self,plazas,velocidad,nuevo):
    self.plazas = plazas
    self.velocidad = velocidad
    self.nuevo = nuevo
```

Usas los parámetros para inicializar los atributos del objeto. El objeto puede tener otros atributos (fecha/hora de creación, por ejemplo), que también puedes inicializar en el constructor.

**¿Qué parámetros pasar a la función?**

Es recomendable que las funciones de cualquier tipo tengan el mínimo de parámetros, para facilitar su entendimiento y correcta aplicación.

No necesitas repetir los parámetros del constructor; esa información ya la grabaste en los atributos del objeto.

Comment: Valee ahora lo entiendo, lo que me faltaría por entender es como le doy valor al parámetro inicializado, ya que dentro del constructor solo inicializamos para que sean accesibles a las funciones, pero no tienen ningún valor, entonces se tendrá que asignar el valor luego en las funciones verdad?

Comment: @Rock. No te entiendo muy bien, pero las variables `self.xxx` conservan su valor durante la existencia del objeto. Las puedes usar dentro de cualquier función (de la misma clase) usando `self.xxx`, que es distinto de `xxx` a secas. Cada objeto de una clase tiene su propio juego de valores.

Comment: class Calculadora():
    def __init__(self,suma,resta,division,multipliacion):

        self.suma = True
        self.resta = resta
        self. = point_spare
        self.division = division
        self.multipliacion = spare_mark

    def frame(self,suma):
 numbers = (2,3,4,5,6,7)
  
 for i in numbers
     if self.suma == True:
  return numbers[0] + numbers[1]

Comment: estari bien así? el codigo esta mal

Comment: pero la forma en que se utiliza el self. estaria bien?

Comment: no se ve bien -_-

Comment: Lo edité arriba, se ve mejor, perdón por ser tan pesado xd, pero tengo que tener esto muy claro.